# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' on compile re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Good Afternoon, I have a problem with regular expressions.
I want to pull a value to the following expression:

```
findall_localizacao_tema = re.compile (':.? (*)' + findall_tema [0] + '/', arquivo_salva)
```

More time to run the code it returns me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "index.py", line 68, in main
    puxar_.Wordpress(executa_comandos[0])
  File "/home/arthur/Projeto-Secreto-do-Arthur/parser.py", line 29, in Wordpress
    findall_localizacao_tema = re.compile(': (.*?)' + findall_tema[0] + '/',arquivo_salva)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 223, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 279, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

What do you think can be already that I'm not adding an integer value more string but a list more strings.

Comment: The second argument for `re.compile()` is the `flags` argument. You are passing in a string, instead of an integer *flags* value.

Comment: If catenation was the problem, your error message would mention `+`, not `&`. We can't guess what your variables contain. Try to reduce the problem to a clear, self-contained, short, clear piece of code.

Comment: Also, `(*)` is not a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the [`re.compile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile), whose second argument is an integer representing the different regular expression flags (such as [`IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) or [`VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X)).

Judging by your variable names, I think you wanted to use the [`re.findall()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead:

```
findall_localizacao_tema = re.findall(
    ':.? (*)' + findall_tema[0] + '/',
    arquivo_salva)
```

You can still use `re.compile`, but then you must use store the resulting `regex` instance and call the [`regex.findall()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.findall):

```
pattern = re.compile(':.? (*)' + findall_tema[0] + '/')
findall_localizacao_tema = pattern.findall(arquivo_salva)
```

Not that your expression is actually valid; you cannot use `*` without something to repeat; nothing precedes your the quantifier (the `(` doesn't count as it defines a group with the `)`).

Comment: Sorry my bad English and thank you for responding so fast, now it generates the following error:
Codigo: compile_localizacao_tema = re.compile(':.? (*)' + findall_tema [0] + '/')

<pre>sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat</pre>

Comment: @ArthurAires: yes, because your pattern is invalid. I mention this in my answer; did you need to capture a literal `*` character or did you want to capture everything between the `:` (plus one optional character) and whatever is stored in `findall_tema[0]`?

Comment: The character: is part of where I want to get the result, in findall_tema is a value needs in regex.

Comment: I'll spend a pastebin with what I take to see if you understand.

Comment: Veja http://pastebin.com/wFc0atJU

Comment: @ArthurAires: so where did the `(. *)` part appear from in your Pastie? Your pattern doesn't use that. Perhaps you meant `(.*)`?

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand

Comment: @ArthurAires: your pastie confuses me too. First you have `Regex: ':.? (*) '+ Findall_tema [0] +' / '` then a few lines down there is `Regex_Final = ': (. *)' + Nome_do_tema + '/'`, which suddenly has `(. *)` where the first line had `(*)`.

Comment: sorry forgot to answer here, most already managed to solve my problem was so take? the regex.